# How to create a dictionary that returns the value(key) in question?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, return-value

I have to create a dictionary (in your file) of four-person from my course and the name of the group they belong to. 
When I run my program it should ask the user to enter a name and return the name of the group of that person back to them. It should look something like this:

```
Welcome to the py-group-infromator, I can tell you where those users belong to:
{name_user}
{name_user}
{name_user}
{name_user}
Which user do you want to ask for?
{name_user}
{name_group}
```

in the beginning

```
notes = ''' "Welcome to the py-group-informator,
    I can tell you where those users belong to" :
    Azura
    Mate
    Anna 
    John 
    " Which user do you want to ask for ?" '''
print(notes)
```

My dictionary

```
people = [{'name': "Azura", 'group': "cute_python"},{'name': "Mate", 'group': "cute_python"},{'name': "Anna", 'group': "fatal_error"},{'name': "John", 'group': "fatal_error"}]
```

Could any help me? Big sorry for my style, this is my first ask ;)

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the other answer but I would write it a tad different:

```py
people = [
    {'name': "Azura", 'group': "cute_python"},
    {'name': "Mate", 'group': "cute_python"},
    {'name': "Anna", 'group': "fatal_error"}, 
    {'name': "John", 'group': "fatal_error"}
]
name_to_group = {d['name']: d['group'] for d in people}

print("Group Information")
names = ', '.join(name_to_group)
name = input(f"Enter one of {names} or 0 to exit: ")
while name != '0':
    if name not in name_to_group:
        continue
    print(f"{name} is in group {name_to_group[name]}")
    name = input(f"Enter one of {names} or 0 to exit: ")
print('Good Bye')
```

Example Output:

```
Group Information
Enter one of Azura, Mate, Anna, John or 0 to exit: Mate
Mate is in group cute_python
Enter one of Azura, Mate, Anna, John or 0 to exit: John
John is in group fatal_error
Enter one of Azura, Mate, Anna, John or 0 to exit: 0
Good Bye
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
people = [
    {'name': "Azura", 'group': "cute_python"},
    {'name': "Mate", 'group': "cute_python"},
    {'name': "Anna", 'group': "fatal_error"}, 
    {'name': "John", 'group': "fatal_error"}
]

def op(names):
    for value in people:
        if value['name'].lower() in names.lower():
            print(value['group'])

x = op(input("Welcome to the py-group-information,I can tell you where 
    those users belong to : Azura Mate  Anna   John Which user do you want 
    to ask for ?"))
```

Comment: Don't just add spaces to the code to make it a code block without indenting the rest of your code. Indenting actually matters in python. Alternatively just create a code block via 3 back ticks which is often easier (see my edit).

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse thanks for 3 backticks, it will save my time indenting with spaces :).

Comment: shouldnt `if value['name'] in ['Azura']:` be `if value['name'] == name:` ?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle Thanks. Edited.

Comment: dont do `in names`, `names`, is just going to be a singe name the user gave not a list. So `names` is just going to be a string and you can just compare with `==`

Answer (score 0):

Following is the core logic to extract from you data structure (purposefully omitting your list and welcome screen text). Assuming you have those, first capture the user input as below and continue to search for group that they belong to.

```
user_name = input("Which user do you want to ask for ?")
    for item in people:
        for key in item:
            if item[key] == user_name:
                    print(item['group'])
                    break
```